# Is my solution to this permutation question correct?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Question:** Suppose there are *m* girls and *n* boys in a class. What is the number of ways of arranging them in a line so that all the girls are together? *(Biggs, Discrete Mathematics 2nd ed, Exercise 10.7.5)*

**My solution**

Say $m=4$ and $n=3$

The number of ways they can be arranged are:

*G - a girl, B - a boy*

```
position 1: [G G G G][B B B]
position 2: [B][G G G G][B B]
position 3: [B B][G G G G][B]
position 4: [B B B][G G G G]
```

So in this case the group of girls can be placed in $4$ different positions. On each position the group of girls can internally be arranged in $4!$ different ways, and the boys can be arranged in $3!$ different ways.

Hence the total number of arrangements are $4!*3!*4$

Converting the answer back to variables, I end up with: $m!*n!*(n + 1)$

The book provides no solution, so I would really like to know if I came up with the right answer..

Comment: It's not really a set theory question.

Comment: Note that $n!(n+1)=(n+1)!$

Comment: sorry my bad, the chapter was all about sets and permutations, just presumed set theory

Comment: @tomasz what category would you suggest?

Comment: Your answer is correct. One way to argue it for general $m$ and $n$ is that we can have $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $\dots$ $n$ boys to the left of the clump of girls, so $n+1$ choices. Multiply $n+1$ by $m!n!$ to account for ordering.  There is a cuter argument that gets you an answer of $(n+1)!m!$ directly.

Comment: @hakanito: Arthur Fischer answered that for you. ;)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea and the answer are correct, but for a complete solution, you should show it in abstract context, so start with arbitrary (unspecified) $m,n$ and try to show that you get $(n+1)!m!$ as a result.